# embed custom form language in Python

Tags: python, embed, abstract-syntax-tree

I have have a Python script that converts files from a custom form language into compilable C++ files. An example of what such a file looks like could be

```py
data = open_special_file_format('data.nc')
f = div(grad(data.u)) + data.g
write_special_file(f, 'out.nc')
```

Note that is Python syntax an in fact is parsed with Python's [ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html). The magic that happens here is mostly in the custom keywords `div`, `grad`, and a few others.

Since this so closely resembles Python, I was asking myself if it is possible to embed this language into Python. I'm imagining something like

```py
import mylang
data = mylang.open_special_file_format('data.nc')
f = mylang.div(mylang.grad(data.u)) + data.g
mylang.write_special_file(f, 'out.nc')
```

I'm not really sure though if it's possible to tell the module `mylang` to create and compile C++ code on the fly and insert it in the right place.

Any hints?

Comment: `I'm not really sure though if it's possible to tell the module mylang to create and compile C++ code on the fly and insert it in the right place.` - I think you should be more specific here.

Comment: From the very small snippet you gave I don't see where is the problem. If the syntax is only a few function calls and operators you can just define some classes that implement the operators and be done.